# Return multiple collections from Firestore database with Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I have an Ionic app, on the service I declared a function which is supposed to obtain multiple collections from a Firestore Database and must return all of them.

I have managed to get one collection on the service section like this:

```
read_Divisions() { 
  return this.firestore.collection('divisions').snapshotChanges();
}
```

And here is the the page typescript

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.crudService.read_Divisions().subscribe(data => {
      this.Divisions = data.map(e => {
        return {
          Name: e.payload.doc.data()['name'],
        };
      })
    });
}
```

This is my idea of the service function for multiple collections:

```
read_Divisions() {
    let divisions = this.firestore.collection('divisions').snapshotChanges();
    let teams = this.firestore.collection('teams').snapshotChanges();
    return [divisions,teams];
}
```

the way I obtain one collection on the page doesn't seem to be easily applicable for an array. What's the best way to go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [forkJoin](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin) to wait for multiple observables, in that case making two separate queries, so probably the code would look like this:

```
readDivisions() {
    return forkJoin({
        divisions: this.firestore.collection('divisions').snapshotChanges(),
        teams: this.firestore.collection('teams').snapshotChanges()
    });
}
```

in another place in your code you would subscribe to `readDivisions`:

```
readDivisions.subscribe(result => console.log(result));
```

it will be smth like:

```
{divisions: [], teams: []}
```